# NToastNotify is not defined error in my .NET Core 3.1 Application

Tags: asp.net-core, toastr

The solution `NToastNotify` was working in .NET Core 2.2 before migration to .NET Core 3.1. Also, I am using the `NToastNotify` NuGet package (v7.0.0) with .NET core 3.1.

> I will get the following two errors GET https://xy.hu/_content/NToastNotify/toastr.js?7.0.0.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 and Uncaught ReferenceError: nToastNotify is not defined

I have added the `app.UseNToastNotify();` middleware in the `Configure` method as well as added the `@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")` bit in the body tag within the layout page.

The `@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")` will actually render the following

```
<script src=/_content/NToastNotify/toastr.js?7.0.0.0 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    if (nToastNotify) {
        nToastNotify.init({
            firstLoadEvent: 'DOMContentLoaded',
            messages: [],
            responseHeaderKey: 'X-NToastNotify-Messages',
            requestHeaderKey: 'X-Requested-With',
            libraryDetails:{"varName":"toastr","scriptSrc":"/js/toastr.min.js","styleHref":"/css/toastr.min.css","options":{"tapToDismiss":true,"positionClass":"toast-bottom-right","timeOut":3000,"newestOnTop":true,"progressBar":true,"title":"","type":"success"}},
            disableAjaxToasts:false
        });
    };
</script>
```

My startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => SetupSerialiserSettings(options.SerializerSettings))
                    .AddNToastNotifyToastr(new ToastrOptions
                    {
                        ProgressBar = true,
                        PositionClass = ToastPositions.BottomRight,
                        TimeOut = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Configuration.GetValue<int>("Notifications:DefaultTimeoutSecs")).TotalMilliseconds,
                        Title = string.Empty,
                        TapToDismiss = true,
                        NewestOnTop = true
                    }, new NToastNotifyOption()
                    {
                        ScriptSrc = "/js/toastr.min.js",
                        StyleHref = "/css/toastr.min.css"
                    });
        ...
        }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {            
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware<LogUserNameMiddleware>();
            app.UseNToastNotify();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        ...
       }
```

This is my _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
    {@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap4-toggle-3.4.0/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/dataTables/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jsgrid/jsgrid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jsgrid/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/toastr/toastr.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    @await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")
</head>
<body>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
    <script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap4-toggle-3.4.0/js/bootstrap4-toggle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-cookie/jquery.cook.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/script.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jsgrid/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js?7.0.0.0 type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="~/js/utils.js"></script>
       
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error is related to your path, please check if it is correct. In addition, are you running in a local environment or another production environment?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved this by created the directories in wwwroot (_content\NToastNotify) and copy there the toastr.js from %userprofile%.nuget\packages\ntoastnotify\7.0.0\staticwebassets. It works for development so far.